# In Vim , how can I copy from several lines? (not a range);

Tags: vim

Assume I have

```
1 - funct1
2- funct 2
3 - funct 3 
4 line 4
```

how can I copy line 1 and 3 (not a range of lines) and paste them, for example at line 8? If I do this in way with `|` arg like ( `1y|3y`), I would yank lines to several registers, right? But how can I put from several registers at once?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can append to a register instead of erasing it by using the upper-case letter instead of the lower-case one.

For example:

```
:1y a      # copy line 1 into register a (erases it beforehand)
:3y A      # copy line 3 into register a (after its current content)
8G  # go to line 8
"ap        # print register a
```

Comment: You can also do this in normal mode with `"ayyjj"Ayy"ap`.

Comment: (or `1G"ayy3G"Ayy8G"ap` for explicit line numbers)

Comment: Isn't it just `G` for go to line, not `<C-G>`?

Comment: This is so cool. You can keep adding as many things to buffer `A` as you want and it'll keep it all. To start over, put something in register `a`

Comment: You can do this all in `ex` mode, with a single command: `:1y a|3y A|8pu a`

Comment: And, in visual mode, you can use (capital) `Y` to yank a line or lines instead of `yy`.

Comment: @CornSmith Nitpick: *buffer* is a very specific term in the context of vim. `"a` is a *register*.

Comment: @Doorknob Good call! Thanks. In case any future readers are curious: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165202/vim-difference-between-buffer-and-register

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:copy` command, which can be abbreviated as `:t`:

```
:1t8
:3t8
```

If you want to copy a range of lines (e.g. all lines from 1 to 3) you can do it like this:

```
:1,3t8
```

Comment: I want to copy lines by number, but not a RANGE OF LINES... Can i with  something like t command append to line?

Answer (score 0):

```
1Gyy7Gp #use 7 if you wish to paste the line at 8
3Gyy8Gp #use 8 if you wish to paste the line at 9
```

Comment: These can be better expressed with the `:t` command, which also doesn't clear the `"` or `0` registers.